# How to design a rank with flexbox?

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox

I'm struggling to put the name club on the left and his rank on the right.

Someone can help me with that ?

I'm trying to use flexDirection 'column' and 'row' but the numbers are always paste to the name club
[image]
let's below my function

```
renderClassement = () => {
    return this.state.sport.clubs.map((element) => {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'column',
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              alignItems: 'flex-end',
            }}>
            <View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 20,
                  textAlign: 'left',
                  color: 'white',
                  marginRight: 130,
                }}>
                {element.nomClub}
              </Text>
            </View>

            <View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'white',
                  textAlign: 'left',
                }}>
                {element.moyenneRank}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    });
  };
```

and also my render

```
render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>{this.renderClassement()}</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Flexbox is for one-dimensions layouts, Grid is for two-dimensional layouts, but you have tabular data here: Use a `<table>`!

Answer (score 0):

This is something you seem to have over complicated in your code below is a working example on stack

```
   this.state = {

       DATA: [{ name: "club1", points: "5" }, { name: "club2", points: "10" }, { name: "club3", points: "15" }, { name: "club4", points: "20" }],

   };
```

dummy state data

```
this.state.DATA.map((element) => {

    return (

           <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'black' }}>

              <Text style={{ fontSize: 20,textAlign: 'left', color: 'white', marginRight: 130, }}> {element.name} </Text>

              <Text style={{ color: 'white', textAlign: 'left', }}> {element.points} </Text>

           </View>

    );
})
```

mapping data

```
return (

    <SafeAreaView>

        <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>

            <View style={{flex: 1}}> {renderClassement()} </View>

        </ScrollView>

    </SafeAreaView>

 );
```

render return

https://snack.expo.io/eYnV2f6U0

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
renderClassement = () => {
    return this.state.sport.clubs.map((element) => {
      return (
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: ‘row’,
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: ‘center’,
              marginHorizontal: 130
            }}>
            <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: 'white',
                }}>
                {element.nomClub}
              </Text>

           <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'white',
                }}>
                {element.moyenneRank}
              </Text>
          </View>
      );
    });
  };





render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View>{this.renderClassement()}</View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: @Quentin I have changed styling friend, please check

Comment: Everything is one the middle now :)

Comment: I just solved it, it was space-between instead to space-evenly, thank you :)